# Struts 1 - Tiles put boolean attribute

Tags: jsp, struts, tiles

Is possible to put a primitive type, like a boolean as attribute?

```
pageContext.setAttribute("boolValue", boolValue);
```

and then

```
<tiles:put name="boolValue" beanName="boolValue" type="boolean" />
```

in the other Jsp I use:

```
<tiles:useAttribute name="boolValue" id="boolValue" classname="boolean" />
```

I get this error:

```
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///BaseBudgetLayout_jsp.java:124: incompatible types
found   : <nulltype>
required: boolean
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
string:///BaseBudgetLayout_jsp.java:125: inconvertible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: boolean
```

Comment: I don't do Tiles, so I have no utter idea about its internals, but first thing I would try is to use `java.lang.Boolean` as type/classname instead. The attribute map can't hold primitives as values. From Java code on, Java 5 autoboxing will silently convert it to `Boolean`, which is not a `boolean` at all. Usually, JSP tags don't do that. At least, that's the theory :) Give it a try in practice.

Comment: Many thanks!! :) it working now! if you give this comment as a response I take your responce as preferred :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute map can't hold primitives as values. Given that it takes `java.lang.Object`, Java 5 autoboxing would silently have turned the `boolean` primitive into a `java.lang.Boolean` instance. This is technically not a `boolean` at all, so the type/classname in your Tiles tags would not match.

Instead, use

```
<tiles:put name="boolValue" beanName="boolValue" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
```

and

```
<tiles:useAttribute name="boolValue" id="boolValue" classname="java.lang.Boolean" />
```